# Warning while executing code for CorePlot

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-plot

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];   
CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)self.view;
hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
pieChart.dataSource = self;
pieChart.pieRadius = 100.0;
pieChart.identifier = @"PieChart1";
pieChart.startAngle = M_PI_4;
pieChart.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionCounterClockwise;

self.pieData=   [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:90.0], 
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:20.0],
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:30.0],
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:40.0],
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:50.0], 
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:60.0], nil];

CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
[graph applyTheme:theme];
[graph addPlot:pieChart];
[pieChart release];
}
```

I found this code on the net.This Code is working fine but am getting two warnings at
      `pieChart.dataSource = self;`

It says.

> warning: class 'SOTC_CorePlotExampleViewController' does not
>   implement the 'CPTPlotDataSource' protocol
>
> warning: Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'id' from
>   incompatible type 'SOTC_CorePlotExampleViewController *'

Comment: Did you have `-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot;` method implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `<CPTPlotDataSource>` to the end of your custom view controller's declaration in your @interface (.h) file:

```
@interface YourViewController  : UIViewController <CPTPlotDataSource>
```

(change YourViewController in my example to whatever the name of your view controller is)

Answer (score 1):

Did you do this?

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController <CPTPlotDataSource>
```

viewController needs to implement the said protocol

Comment: great! u r welcome. If it has hepled you do consider accepting the answer. An upvote will not hurt :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to import the protocols in .h file "CPTPlotDataSource" like `@interface:UIViewController < CPTPlotDataSource >`